# How To remove Manage 'e' element in xmlserialzer

Tags: java, xml, json, xml-serialization, xmlserializer

I am using xml serializer to convert my JSON output to XML. but i am getting element  in xml output. How to manage this. My input json string will be like below.

```
String responseBodyStr = "{\"spimObject\":[{\"client\":\"test1\",\"createDate\":1399641291687,\"createdBy\":\"dan\",\"endDate\":1407535200000,\"phase\":\"Doing\",\"projDesc\":\"Description\",\"projName\":\"Project 1832\",\"startDate\":1394319600000,\"_id\":\"536cd4cbe4b0265e5978fbcd\",\"owner\":\"dan\"},{\"client\":\"HP\",\"createDate\":1399641326758,\"createdBy\":\"dan\",\"endDate\":1407535200000,\"phase\":\"Doing\",\"projDesc\":\"Description\",\"projName\":\"Project 1832\",\"startDate\":1394319600000,\"_id\":\"536cd4eee4b0265e5978fbce\",\"owner\":\"dan\"},{\"client\":\"Swiss\",\"createDate\":1399911549732,\"createdBy\":\"dan\",\"endDate\":1402524000000,\"phase\":\"Doing\",\"projDesc\":\"Hotel for Swiss of 500 bedrooms\",\"projName\":\"Swiss\",\"startDate\":1399845600000,\"_id\":\"5370f47de4b0265e5978fbd9\",\"owner\":\"dan\"},{\"client\":\"Best Western\",\"createDate\":1400245867385,\"createdBy\":\"dan\",\"endDate\":1402869600000,\"phase\":\"Doing\",\"projDesc\":\"Description\",\"projName\":\"test2\",\"startDate\":1400191200000,\"_id\":\"53760e6be4b0265e5978fbda\",\"owner\":\"dan\"},{\"client\":\"Best Western\",\"createDate\":1400589659884,\"createdBy\":\"dan\",\"endDate\":1403215200000,\"phase\":\"Doing\",\"projDesc\":\"Description\",\"projName\":\"hotel\",\"startDate\":1400536800000,\"_id\":\"537b4d5be4b0265e5978fbdb\",\"owner\":\"dan\"}]}";
```

Output is comming as:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<o><spimObject><e><_id>536cd4cbe4b0265e5978fbcd</_id><client>test1</client><createDate>1399641291687</createDate><createdBy>dan</createdBy><endDate>1407535200000</endDate><owner>dan</owner><phase>Doing</phase><projDesc>Description</projDesc><projName>Project 1832</projName><startDate>1394319600000</startDate></e><e><_id>536cd4eee4b0265e5978fbce</_id><client>HP</client><createDate>1399641326758</createDate><createdBy>dan</createdBy><endDate>1407535200000</endDate><owner>dan</owner><phase>Doing</phase><projDesc>Description</projDesc><projName>Project 1832</projName><startDate>1394319600000</startDate></e><e><_id>5370f47de4b0265e5978fbd9</_id><client>Swiss</client><createDate>1399911549732</createDate><createdBy>dan</createdBy><endDate>1402524000000</endDate><owner>dan</owner><phase>Doing</phase><projDesc>Hotel for Swiss of 500 bedrooms</projDesc><projName>Swiss</projName><startDate>1399845600000</startDate></e><e><_id>53760e6be4b0265e5978fbda</_id><client>Best Western</client><createDate>1400245867385</createDate><createdBy>dan</createdBy><endDate>1402869600000</endDate><owner>dan</owner><phase>Doing</phase><projDesc>Description</projDesc><projName>test2</projName><startDate>1400191200000</startDate></e><e><_id>537b4d5be4b0265e5978fbdb</_id><client>Best Western</client><createDate>1400589659884</createDate><createdBy>dan</createdBy><endDate>1403215200000</endDate><owner>dan</owner><phase>Doing</phase><projDesc>Description</projDesc><projName>hotel</projName><startDate>1400536800000</startDate></e></spimObject></o>
```

My java Code logic:-

```
if(JSONSerializer.toJSON(responseBodyStr) instanceof JSONArray){
    jsonArray = (JSONArray)JSONSerializer.toJSON(responseBodyStr);
    XMLSerializer xmlSerializer = new XMLSerializer();
    xmlSerializer.setRemoveNamespacePrefixFromElements(true);
    xmlSerializer.setSkipNamespaces(true);
    xmlSerializer.clearNamespaces();
    xmlSerializer.setTypeHintsEnabled(false);

    jsonXmlString = xmlSerializer.write(jsonArray);
}else if (JSONSerializer.toJSON(responseBodyStr) instanceof JSONObject) {
    jsonObject = (JSONObject) JSONSerializer.toJSON(responseBodyStr);
    XMLSerializer xmlSerializer = new XMLSerializer();
    xmlSerializer.setTypeHintsEnabled(false);
    xmlSerializer.setRemoveNamespacePrefixFromElements(true);
    xmlSerializer.setSkipNamespaces(true);
    xmlSerializer.clearNamespaces();
    jsonXmlString = xmlSerializer.write(jsonObject);
}


System.out.println("jsonXmlString is:\n" + jsonXmlString);


return jsonXmlString;
```

Added the Json Input:-

{"spimObject":[{"client":"test1","createDate":1399641291687,"createdBy":"dan","endDate":1407535200000,"phase":"Doing","projDesc":"Description","projName":"Project 1832","startDate":1394319600000,"_id":"536cd4cbe4b0265e5978fbcd","owner":"dan"},
{"client":"HP","createDate":1399641326758,"createdBy":"dan","endDate":1407535200000,"phase":"Doing","projDesc":"Description","projName":"Project 1832","startDate":1394319600000,"_id":"536cd4eee4b0265e5978fbce","owner":"dan"},
{"client":"Swiss","createDate":1399911549732,"createdBy":"dan","endDate":1402524000000,"phase":"Doing","projDesc":"Hotel for Swiss of 500 bedrooms","projName":"Swiss","startDate":1399845600000,"_id":"5370f47de4b0265e5978fbd9","owner":"dan"},
{"client":"Best Western","createDate":1400245867385,"createdBy":"dan","endDate":1402869600000,"phase":"Doing","projDesc":"Description","projName":"test2","startDate":1400191200000,"_id":"53760e6be4b0265e5978fbda","owner":"dan"},
{"client":"Best Western","createDate":1400589659884,"createdBy":"dan","endDate":1403215200000,"phase":"Doing","projDesc":"Description","projName":"hotel","startDate":1400536800000,"_id":"537b4d5be4b0265e5978fbdb","owner":"dan"}]}

Comment: can you plz place the well formatted JSON here. It is not possible to read the json at all like this

Comment: Hi, I have updates the query with Json Input again at the end. Let me know if its fine.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Can you clarify more that what you want to do? You are not explaining what your issue is?

Comment: when there is array of elements the xmlserializer print "e" as element name for the list of values. i want to remove that "e" element name and print the result without that.